How do I make all these arcs exactly positioned like that

I want to create these arcs through css such that upon hovering it changes its color to green from grey.
I want these arcs to be dynamic so that it fits in its parent container and adjusts itself.
It's awfully painful to make these arcs in a single line, coz these are basically some part of the circle. So the center keeps shifting.
Any idea on how this can be achieved?


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.size-selector {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.size {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.size span {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

#size-s .arc {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 6em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  width: 6em;
}

#size-m .arc {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

#size-l .arc {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#size-xl .arc {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12em;
  height: 12em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#size-xx .arc {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14em;
  height: 14em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.size:hover .arc {
  border-color: limegreen;
}

#size-l:hover .arc {
  border-color: green;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.size:hover span {
  color: limegreen;
}

#size-l:hover span {
  color: green;
}

.arc-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
<div class="size-selector arc-container">
  <div class="size" id="size-s"><span>S</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-m"><span>M</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-l"><span>L</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-xl"><span>XL</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-xx"><span>XX</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>




what have you try ? where are you stuck ?

Either use an SVG path, or a simple html element with border + border radius. We need more details on what you tried and what exactly is the problem? If it is just having a hard time fitting them to the parent container, then show us how you do it so we can help.

added details, if you guys can please take a look again

"I want these arcs to be dynamic so that it fits in it's parent container and adjusts itself." - in your image, they all look the same size (which means each column is of equal width, regardless of the text content), whereas in your snippet, they are all different sizes. So which one is it supposed to be?

the first image,
the difference is very subtle.
if you compare small and XXL you can spot the difference pretty quickly.
the height and arcs start and end point is different.

Are the arcs just for visual effect? If so you may like to look into using pseudo elements rather than put otherwise spurious extra elements into the HTML.

The trick is the make the centers of the circles to be in 1 line. Then you can arrange the arcs as per your requirement.
Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/vmnqky59/


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.size-selector {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.size {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  top:150px;
}

.size span {
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  top: -130px;
}

#size-s  {
  left: 0;
}

#size-s .arc {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 6em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
 /*  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent; */
  width: 6em;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  
}
#size-m {
  left: 120px;
}
#size-m .arc {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
/*   border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent; */
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  
}
#size-l {
  left: 240px;
}
#size-l .arc {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
 /*  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent; */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
#size-xl {
  left: 405px;
}
#size-xl .arc {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12em;
  height: 12em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid black;
  /* border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent; */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
#size-xx {
  left: 600px;
}
#size-xx .arc {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14em;
  height: 14em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid black;
  /* border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent; */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.size:hover .arc {
  border-color: limegreen;
}

#size-l:hover .arc {
  border-color: green;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.size:hover span {
  color: limegreen;
}

#size-l:hover span {
  color: green;
}

.arc-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
<div class="size-selector arc-container">
  <div class="size" id="size-s"><span>S</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-m"><span>M</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-l"><span>L</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-xl"><span>XL</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-xx"><span>XX</span>
    <div class="arc"></div>
  </div>
</div>




appreciate the answer, but semi circles isn't what I'm looking for.
the job is to make arcs of different sizes and different start and end point.

in the css class .size-selector, we have the property height: 144px;. You can decrease the height to obtain the arc of your choice. Also having border-width: 1px 0 0 0; would result in arc, and not semi circle. I mainly focused on the concept.

but then it messes the position of the letters (S, m,..), they are not in a same line

I've edited the answer to fit your requirement. I updated the size of the .size-selector { height: 120px; }. Made all the labels(S, M, etc.) as positon: absolute and aligned them in one line.

I changed the width for all the arcs to 100% which makes the page responsive.
But I'm not able to set dynamic height. If I set to any percentage, the arc disappears.
any idea on that?

I'd suggest a slightly different approach, where the arcs are put in place as borders of after pseudo elements rather than adding otherwise unneeded elements to the DOM.
This snippet also uses grid as it's easier to control for a 2d layout.
Of course you will want to play with the variables to get the exact layout you want but as everything is specified in % terms it is responsive.
arcs rather than circles are achieved simply by using a clip-path.


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.size-selector {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 0 60%);
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.size {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.size:hover {
  color: lime;
}

.size::after {
  content: '';
  --w: 70%;
  --extra: 1%;
  --offset: 10%;
  width: calc(var(--w) + (var(--n) * var(--extra)));
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 2px gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: calc(100% + (6 - var(--n)) * var(--offset));
  left: 50%;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.size:hover::after {
  border-color: lime;
}

.size-selector :nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

.size-selector :nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

.size-selector :nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

.size-selector :nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}

.size-selector :nth-child(5) {
  --n: 5;
}
<div class="size-selector arc-container">
  <div class="size" id="size-s">S
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-m">M
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-l">L
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-xl">XL
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="size-xx">XX
  </div>



